# I am trying to pop up an alert in javascript but nothing happens

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in javascript and i'm trying to pop up an alert box given conditions. However, nothing pops up in my code. The page refreshes and the url bar contains the information i entered in the form. What's wrong with my code?

```
function validateform(form)
{
 var self = 1;
 var spouse = 1;
 var mom = 1;
 var dad = 1;
 var educ = 1;
 var work = 1; 
 var elig = 1;

if((form.country.value == "Bangladesh" || form.country.value == "Brazil" || form.country.value == "Canada" || form.country.value == "China" || form.country.value == "Colombia" || form.country.value == "Dominican Republic" || form.country.value == "Ecuador" || form.country.value == "El Salvador" || form.country.value == "Haiti" )|| (form.country.value == "India" || form.country.value == "Jamaica" || form.country.value == "Mexico" || form.country.value == "Nigeria" || form.country .value == "Pakistan" || form.country.value == "Peru" || form.country.value == "Philippines" || form.country.value == "South Korea" || form.country.value == "United Kingdom" || form.country.value == "Vietnam"))
{
    self = 0;
}

if((form.countryspouse.value = '' || form.countryspouse.value == "Bangladesh" || form.countryspouse.value == "Brazil" || form.countryspouse.value == "Canada" || form.countryspouse.value == "China" || form.countryspouse.value == "Colombia" || form.countryspouse.value == "Dominican Republic" || form.countryspouse.value == "Ecuador" || form.countryspouse.value == "El Salvador" || form.countryspouse.value == "Haiti" )|| (form.countryspouse.value == "India" || form.countryspouse.value == "Jamaica" || form.countryspouse.value == "Mexico" || form.countryspouse.value == "Nigeria" || form.countryspouse.value == "Pakistan" || form.countryspouse.value == "Peru" || form.countryspouse.value == "Philippines" || form.countryspouse.value == "South Korea" || form.countryspouse.value == "United Kingdom" || form.countryspouse.value == "Vietnam"))
{
    spouse = 0;
}

if((form.countrydad.value == "Bangladesh" || form.countrydad.value == "Brazil" || form.countrydad.value == "Canada" || form.countrydad.value == "China" || form.countrydad.value == "Colombia" || form.countrydad.value == "Dominican Republic" || form.countrydad.value == "Ecuador" || form.countrydad.value == "El Salvador" || form.countrydad.value == "Haiti" )|| (form.countrydad.value == "India" || form.countrydad.value == "Jamaica" || form.countrydad.value == "Mexico" || form.countrydad.value == "Nigeria" || form.countrydad.value == "Pakistan" || form.countrydad.value == "Peru" || form.countrydad.value == "Philippines" || form.countrydad.value == "South Korea" || form.countrydad.value == "United Kingdom" || form.countrydad.value == "Vietnam"))
{
    dad = 0;
}

if((form.countrymom.value == "Bangladesh" || form.countrymom.value == "Brazil" || form.countrymom.value == "Canada" || form.countrymom.value == "China" || form.countrymom.value == "Colombia" || form.countrymom.value == "Dominican Republic" || form.countrymom.value == "Ecuador" || form.countrymom.value == "El Salvador" || form.countrymom.value == "Haiti" )|| (form.countrymom.value == "India" || form.countrymom.value == "Jamaica" || form.countrymom.value == "Mexico" || form.countrymom.value == "Nigeria" || form.countrymom.value == "Pakistan" || form.countrymom.value == "Peru" || form.countrymom.value == "Philippines" || form.countrymom.value == "South Korea" || form.countrymom.value == "United Kingdom" || form.countrymom.value == "Vietnam"))
{
    mom = 0;
}

if(form.education.value == "noeducation")
{
    educ = 0;
}

if(form.occupation.value == "None")
{
    work = 0;
}

if(((educ + work) == 0 )||((self + spouse + parents) == 0 ))
{
    alert("Sorry, you are ineligible.");
}else
{
    alert("You are eligible.");
}
    }
```

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for your code

Comment: `validateform` is a function, what are you using to call that function? As you have an alert in `if` and `else`, if you are getting neither then the chances are your function is not being called.

Comment: @wf4 , i am calling the function in the submit button. It's in the onclick. It was working before when only alert was inside the function then when i added this, no pop-ups happen. Is there like a limit to conditions inside an if statement?

Comment: There's no limit - there's probably some sort of logic error

Answer (score 0):

`'parents' is undefined`

If you take a look in your console, it looks like you are using 'parents' in your `if` statement but it does not exist.

If you remove `parents` or add `var parents = 1;` it will work.

You should also take a look in your `if` statements. You are using a single equals `=` instead of a double `==` or triple `===` equals.

Single will set a value, double and triple will compare - only difference is that with a triple, they also must be the same type to return true.

e.g.

```
1 = 1      -- will set int 1 with a value of 1
1 == "1"   -- will return true (int compared to a string)
1 === "1"  -- will return false (int compared to a string)
```

Comment: thanks, i think i just did not notice that, i should really be more patient in checking syntax errors. :)